# Lua Newbie stuck on simple input

Tags: lua, intellij-idea, luajava, luaj

I'm trying to pick up Lua programming but I'm stuck on something that's probably trivial. I'm prototyping some Lua scripts using Kahlua from IntelliJ Idea 11 and I keep getting errors whenever I try to use io.read(). Here's what I currently have:

```
require "io"

print("input:")
a = io.read()        -- read a number
print(a)
```

When I run it in Idea I get "Tried to call nil
at interpreter:1" If I remove the require and the blank line after it I get "input:
attempted index of non-table: null
at interpreter:2" What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kahula doesn't support the `io` library.

Your best bet would be to set up a real Lua SDK, and use the run lua console feature.

See:  http://www.screencast.com/t/0f262SeCKmqT

Comment: I finally figured the same on my own back in February. I'd been running via the console feature ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this? (adding `local io` to the beginning)

```
local io = require "io"

print("input:")
a = io.read()        -- read a number
print(a)
```

Comment: Nope, I think it's a bug in the plugin. The normal Lua runtime accepts all flavors of my code just fine. One of those toe-stubbers of picking up a new language by using an IDE plugin.